# Excel VBA hide/show/move Shape

Tags: vba, excel

Am trying to hide or move a series of shapes in excel.

I have a range of cells that I want to copy as a picture and basically if the shape isn't 'active' i.e. contains text then I don't want the shapes to be visable in this range of cells. Each shape is linked and if the if/vlookup is true the shape will contain text.

The following is not working - have tried modifying .Visable with .Right i.e. to shift the shapes out of range - but it says object does not support this property or method.

```
 Sub Macro3()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 Dim shp As Shape
 Dim tr As TextRange2
 Dim grp As Shape
 Dim sShape As Shape

 Set shp = ws.Shapes("Line Callout 1 2")
 Set tr = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange

 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In ws
            If shp.Name Like "Line Callout 1" And tr.Characters.Text = "" Then
                sShape.Right = 300
            Else
                sShape.Right = 0
            End If
    Next shp
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

If I specify a named cell I can alter the visability but for over 600 shapes I want to auomate this somehow This works for named shape and named range:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Line Callout 1 1"))
       .Fill.Visible = Range("x")
       .Line.Visible = Range("x")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each shp In ws` should be `For Each shp In ws.Shapes`

Comment: Have made this amend and now '91' get object or with block variable not set

Comment: Which line does the new error come on?

Comment: Its line 17 = sShape.Right = 0